# How many roots exists in common usage and officially compared to other languages?

Tags: akademia-vortaro

In the Unua Libro, Zamenhof presented some 900 roots that can be used to form a wide variety of Esperanto words. As far as I know, in later conferences new lists of words were added to the official list of roots. At the same time, Esperanto speakers invent and adopt new roots into common usage which are not necessarily part of any official list (yet).

How many roots are there in total (officially and unofficially), and how does this compare to other languages which can make compound words such as German, Finnish or Russian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Akademio de Esperanto](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademia_vortaro/klarigoj.html) there are **2.768 fundamental roots** and **2.185 official roots**, making a total of **4.953 roots**.

> [...] 7OA: “La fina sumo de la Fundamentaj kaj Oficialaj Radikoj estas
>   do: 2.759 + 1.777 = 4.536.”
>
> Post tio 8OA rekonis ankoraŭ 13 Fundamentajn elementojn [...] kaj
>   aldonis 200 pliajn elementojn. En 9OA la Akademio aldonis ankoraŭ 209
>   radikojn. Tio donas la jenan ĝisdatigon de la kalkulo en 7OA:
>
> 2755 + 13 = 2768 Fundamentaj elementoj
>
> 1776 + 200 + 209 = 2185 oficialaj elementoj
>
> 2768 + 2185 = **4953**

Comment: @ahemmetter: I realized too late that you are not asking about the sum of fundamental and official roots, but about the total number of existing roots in Esperanto (including invented or loaned ones). My mistake. I'll delete my answer if you consider it totally irrelevant.

Comment: No no, this is already a good number for what I am looking for, it is certainly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that nobody can answer this, for any language. The Esperanto-ĉina vortaro by Honfan has 18,300 roots and is considered one of the biggest dictionaries. But it is a general dictionary. So you should add to your calculation all the roots in special dictionaries ("terminaroj"), like for instance the "Orgena vortaro" with roots only about organs, or "Likenoj de Okcidenta Europo. Ilustrita determinlibro" just about lichens...