# How many of Zamenhof's 917 original Esperanto roots does the Duolingo course cover?

Tags: akademia-vortaro, duolingo

The *Unua Libro*'s dictionary section contains 917 roots. (Later many additional roots were added to the language.)

**How many of Zamenhof's 917 original Esperanto roots does the Duolingo course cover?**

If anyone would alternatively like to answer how many roots among the [2768 fundamental roots and 2185 official roots](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/4783/4948) the course covers, I would find that interesting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nur ili povus respondi tion, ĉar la aktuala plena enhavo por ĉiu lingvo ne estas libere akirebla (laŭ mia scio). Iam tio alireblis kaj tiutempe iu kreis retejon kun tiuj informoj. Ĝi ne estas nepre ankoraŭ ĝisdata, sed [jen tiama listo de vortoj en la esperanta](https://duome.eu/vocabulary/en/eo) (el la angla).

Mi ŝatus tamen rimarki ke tre verŝajne neniu kurso atingos 100% de tiaj radikoj, ĉar kelkaj estas vere ne tre uzataj (aŭ uzeblaj). Mi pensas ekzemple pri `fraŭl/`.

Aliaj radikoj perdis sian lokon en la normale uzata lingvo. Ekzemple, la lokon de `ventol-` prenis `aer-um-` (kaj ankaŭ parte `vent-um-`). En la evoluo de la lingvo, tio logikas ĉar per malpli da elementoj oni povas diri same multe kiel antaŭe.

Cetere, radikoj kiel `draŝ-` aperus nur en fakaj tekstoj. Tre verŝajne oni povas vivi plenan esperantoparolantan vivon sen iam ajm lerni aŭ uzi ilin.

Laste, eĉ se oni havus la kompletajn tekstojn, [ŝajnaj kunmetaĵoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/shajnkunmetajhoj.html) malhelpus eltrovi ekzakte kiuj radikoj kaj afiksoj estis uzitaj.